# How can I dispay a calculated value to the tab title and the project file entry in an intellij plugin?

Tags: intellij-plugin

I am calculating a value for each file in a project. I can successfully display it in a popup window with

```
class ComplexityCalcAction : AnAction() {
    override fun actionPerformed(e: AnActionEvent) {
        val complexityVisitor = ComplexityVisitor(4)
        val editor = e.getData(CommonDataKeys.EDITOR)
        e.getData(CommonDataKeys.PSI_FILE)
            ?.accept(complexityVisitor)

        editor?.let {
            JBPopupFactory.getInstance().createMessage("Complexity: ${complexityVisitor.complexity}").showInBestPositionFor(it)
        }
    }
}
```

But I want to put the results by the class name in the tab title and next to the class name in the project window. Is this possible in an intellij plugin?